# How do I express ''routine'' in the following cases?

Tags: word-choice

I want to say "workout routine" , "weightlifting routine" , "daily routine" , "study routine".

My dictionary provides a few translations for "routine".

套路，定例，例行

Which is the best for my examples above ?

Comment: I just want to chime in that if you want to describe a routine for emphasis 定例
is good, but still with the description of when. 每星期六我騎馬，（這已成定例了。） as others said, these words are totally optional to emphasize being a routine and you can just say you do it however often.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be honest, this is not used a lot in conversation (as far as I know), but if you were to use it, you use 例行。We usually just directly say 每天去锻炼，我给锻炼制定了一个计划. I would advise not to use a direct translation of English to Chinese for the idea of routine (try to be descriptive instead).

Workout routine: 例行锻炼/例行健身
weightlifting routine: 例行举重
daily routine: 日常行程//日常生活；this is not usually used that much so it depends on context;
study routine: 学习计划（study plan) 学习安排, and it sounds very weird to say 例行学习...

Depending on context, say study routine, you could say 我开始我的例行学习了,(I'm starting my study routine), but that hardly ever appears in conversation.

Usually it's like
老样子，我开始学习了。(Gonna study like always）

我学习按计划走了 （Studying according to plan)

老样子，去健身去了。 (Gonna workout like what was before)

你有什么健身计划吗？(Got any workout plans?)

Or be specific:
卧推你做几组？(How many times you bench pressing?)
去做几组...几套... 去了(Gonna go do several ..., several...)

Answer (score 1):

> I want to say "workout routine" , "weightlifting routine" , "daily routine" , "study routine".

Google Translate gives a good answer: “鍛煉程序”、“舉重程序”、“日常程序”、“學習程序” (routine --> program --> what to do in details, when to do, and for how long, basically a course)

編排 is also a suitable translation “鍛煉編排”、“舉重編排”、“日常編排”、“學習編排” (routine --> arrangement--> what to do in general, when to do, and for how long, basically a time table)